# How run script Python GTK and Glade in windows?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, msys2

> Sorry about my English, i want to create an application with windows interface, through the website [Setting up GTK for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/) I followed all MSYS2 steps to install GTK and Glade for windows. But now I can't find Glade, I can't run a python script.

Answer (score 0):

About the second problem:

For me, it is sufficient to search for Glade with Windows' search function. If this is not the case for you, I have the direct executable path for you: `glade.exe` should be located in `[..., folder where you installed msys2 to]\msys2\mingw64\bin\glade.exe`.